# Commercially free to use font, where M and W are the same

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, free, royalty-free

I want to do an animated logo with CSS. For this I need a commercially free to use font, where (for the purpose of the animation I'm imagining) the letters M an W are basically the same, just flipped upside down. An example font that would fit the M-W criteria would be [Lithos Pro](https://typekit.com/fonts/lithos-pro), but this is not a free to use font.

I'd be thankful for recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several 100% free for commercial use options available on dafont:
Gladifilthefte
http://www.dafont.com/gladifilthefte.font?fpp=100&l[]=10&l[]=1&text=MW

Viafont
http://www.dafont.com/viafont.font?fpp=100&l[]=10&l[]=1&text=MW

Ashby
http://www.dafont.com/ashby.font?fpp=100&l[]=10&l[]=1&text=MW

Comment: Viafont has the added bonus that A and V are also identical-but-flipped, so you can be a disgruntled Texan teenager (“Aw, ma!”) from both directions.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I didn't know that site. Very enlightning ;-)

Comment: Just be sure to observe the license for each font, even on dafont. Not all of them are free for commercial use like the ones I listed. Even if you do use one of the free fonts for a job, it's always a good idea to toss come coin to whoever designed the typeface you profited by using. It's just good manners! Peace.